# Dict of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say I initialize a df and then I assign it to a dict 3 times, each one with a specific key.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 2], 'B': [2, 2]})

dict = {}

for i in range(3):
    dict_strat['Df {0}'.format(i)] = df
```

Alright, what I'm not understanding is that when I try to change value of one element in the dictionary, it changes all the others. For example:

```
dict_strat['Df 0'].iloc[0, :] = 9
```

It not only changes the first df on the dict, it changes all of them. Why? How can I get rid of that?

Comment: dict_strat['Df 0'] = df.copy()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataFrames are all shallow copies, meaning that mutating one of them will mutate the others in the dictionary.

To resolve this issue, make deep copies using `.copy()`. You also should be using f-strings rather than `.format()`:

```py
for i in range(3):
    dict_strat[f'Df {i}'] = df.copy()
```

Answer (score 2):

what you do is a shallow copy you need to do a deep copy. you can use `df.copy()`

```
dict_strat['Df {0}'.format(i)] = df.copy()
```